# Simplify the probability of events

Tags: probability, independence

Given three exhaustive events $X, Y$ and $Z$, $X$ and $Y$ are mutually exclusive, and $X$ and $Z$ are independent. If $P(X) = m, P(Y) = n$ and $P(z) = m$, express the following in terms of $m$ and $n$: $P(Z|X\cup Y)$

I'm not sure how to simplify this except using the fundamentals of conditional probability:

$$P(Z|X\cup Y) = \frac{P(Z \cap (X \cup Y))}{P(X \cup Y)}$$

I also know that $P(X\cup Y) = P(X) + P(Y) = m + n$.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$P(Z\cap(X \cup Y))=P((Z\cap X)\cup (Z \cap Y)) = P(Z \cap X) + P(Z \cap Y)$ because $X$ and $Y$ are mutually exclusive.

$P(Z \cap X) + P(Z \cap Y) = P(Z)P(X) + P(Z \cap Y) = m^2 + P(Z \cap Y)$ as $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

$P(Z \cap Y)=P(Z \cap \bar{X})$, as $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are exhaustive. But $P(Z \cap \bar{X})=P(Z)P(\bar{X})=m(1-m)$ as $Z$ and $X$ (and therefore $\bar{X}$) are independent.

So, $P(Z|X \cup Y) = \frac{m^2 + m(1-m)}{m + n}=\frac{m}{m+n}$.

Comment: True... I'm not very sure how to find $P(Z\cap Y)$

Comment: I think I worked it out; see the edited answer.

Comment: What if you write $Y = (Y\cap Z) \cup (Y\cap Z')$, which implies $P(Y) = P(Y\cap Z) + P(Y\cap Z')$. And $P(Y\cap Z') = P(Z') - P(Z' \cap X)$ from the law of total probability. Would this work?

Comment: I updated my latest comment...